# Meaning of "Noe" in Medieval Latin carols

Tags: vocabulary, medieval-latin

Many Medieval Latin hymns, such as ["Noe, Noe, psallite"](http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Noe,_noe_psallite_(Jean_Mouton)) by Jean Mouton (1459-1522), use the word "Noe" in the context of Christmas.

My first thought was that it is related to "Noel," used in many English carols like "The First Noel." [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=noel) gives the following explanation of "Noel."

> late 14c., nowel "feast of Christmas," from Old French noel "the Christmas season," variant of nael, **from Latin natalis (dies) "birth (day)," in Church Latin in reference to the birthday of Christ, from natus**, past participle of nasci "be born" (Old Latin gnasci; see genus). The modern word in English, with the sense "a Christmas carol" (1811) probably is a separate borrowing from French. As a masc. proper name, from Old French, probably literally "of or born on Christmas."

However, "Noe" has its own apparently unrelated trajectory: it is the word used for Noah in the Vulgate (cf. [Gen 5](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/vul/gen006.htm)), as borne out by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Noe#Latin):

> Borrowing from Ancient Greek Νῶε ‎(Nôe), from Hebrew נֹחַ ‎(Nōaḥ).

A final (speculative) etymology that comes to my mind is that "Noel" is a shortening of "Emmanuel," which figures in Isaiah's birth prophecy (and which is hence associated with Christmas), and that "Noe" is just a Latinization of "Noel."

My question:

1. When did "Noe" start occurring in the context of Christ/Christmas.
2. What is its intended meaning and origin?

Comment: I wouldn't cite without fact-checking Etymonline or Wiktionary in an answer, but I figure they count for a quesiton's due diligence.

Comment: Could you add why you say that Noe refers to a person in that song? I don't know anything about Christmas carols or psalms, but the lines work for me if I simply read Noe as "birth".

Comment: @Cerberus Now I feel stupid, but I think you're right that it's just a kind of exclamation. I guess I saw "Noe, iacet in praesepio" but it's clear that the other Noe's are just interjections. Most of the question still stands, even if that seems to heavily favor the first interpretation

Comment: Absolutely, the question stands and I'm interested in whatever answer people come up with. Perhaps an answerer could look at one or more other carols to confirm whether or not Noe is aequivalent to Noel. An explanation of the spelling Noe would also be interesting.

Comment: In French, noël is an exclamation: http://www.littre.org/definition/no%C3%ABl It comes from *natalis*.

I suppose this *noe* is the same?

Comment: I think your speculation about "Noel" being a shortening of "Emmanuel" may well be correct. A long time ago, I heard Bishop Barry of Southwell, in a Christmas sermon, tell the congregation that "Nowell" (the spelling in the carol) was exactly that, the angel addressing the shepherds indicating "God is with us", meaning that the Messiah had been born.

Comment: @TomCotton. Noel comes from natalis, not from Emmanuel. Your Bishop was engaging in folk etymology.

Comment: Just a side note: “Noel” was also used at least once for the name of Noah in a now lost mosaic at the Notre Dame de la Daraude church at Toulouse (southern France), likely due to Gothic influence, since the Goths used  (pronounced “Noël”) for the name of Noah. See: https://brill.com/view/journals/abag/80/1-2/article-p5_2.xml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Is it used only in the context of Christmas?

Yes.  When used to refer to Noah, it is clearly signposted as such: “patres nostri Noe, Abraham, Aaron, David et Jesus” from *Laudemus nunc Dominum*, Jacob Obrecht, 1457/8-1505, http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Laudemus_nunc_Dominum_(Jacob_Obrecht)

### When did *noe* start occurring in the context of Christ/Christmas?

Earliest I could find is in the **1400s** (*O admirabile commercium*, Johannes Regis, Netherlandish, c. 1425 – c. 1496).  Latest, late 1500s-early 1600s (*Noe, noe*, Gregor Aichinger, German, c. 1565-1628)

### How is it used?

It does appear to be used as an interjection or exclamation much like amen or alleluia.  Evidence for this is as follows:

- It is typically tacked onto the end of lines much like *amen* or *alleluia*, the following being a good example (from *Pastores dicite*):

> *Pastores dicite, quidnam vidistis, et annuntiate Christi nativitatem,
>   noe* / Tell us, shepherds, what did you see, and announce the birth of
>   Christ, noe
>     *Infantem vidimus pannis involutum et choros angelorum
>   laudantes salvatorem, noe* / We saw the infant wrapped in swaddling
>   clothes and the choirs of angels praising the Saviour, noe

- It sometimes even occurs as an alternative to *alleluia*: see *Pastores loquebantur*, http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Pastores_loquebantur
- It is used in an otherwise German-language hymn, thus highlighting its sense as an interjection:  *Noe, noe*, Gregor Aichinger
- It is always translated as *noel* in English which itself, from the early 14th century, was used as an exclamation of joy generally and more particularly to commemorate the birth of Christ (OED).  Thus, clearly *noe* has been understood also as an exclamation.
- In *Quaeramus cum pastoribus* it is a one-word utterance of the angels and shepherds:

> *Angelos cum carmine et pastores dicentes: Noe* / Angels with song and
>   shepherds saying: Noe

### What is its intended meaning and origin?

- The Vulgate uses *Noe* only to refer to Noah.  All dictionaries consulted list Noah as its meaning however it is clearly not referring to Noah in these hymns (with one exception as noted above).
- Is it a Latinised form of *noel*?  Maybe.  As mentioned previously, *noel* certainly was used as an interjection in English and French for joy generally (appearing circa **1300** in Old French; circa **1342-1400** in English (OED)) and then more particularly for marking the birth of Christ.  I think it is clear from my notes above that the use of *noe* is also as an exclamation of joy.
- Additionally, as far as I can tell, *noel/nowell* started appearing in secular carols around the early **1400s** (see below).  Thus, *noel* (in secular, vernacular music) and *noe* (in sacred, Latin music) began to appear in Christmas songs at about the same time.
- There is evidence that, in French at least, *noel* was not always pronounced no-ell.  Some variations given are: *noé, nau, and nô*, with the earliest attested use of *noé* being in Rutebeuf, **1230-1285**  see: http://www.littre.org/definition/no%C3%ABl  One French carol that is still easily found online and which apparently dates from the 14th or 15th century is *Nau, nau, nau, naulet*, *nau* being *noel* in the Anjou dialect and *naulet* a diminutive – see: http://www.mamalisa.com/?t=es&p=2164 and also https://archive.org/details/vieuxnolscompos01meiggoog   It is possible, therefore, that Latin *noe* is somehow echoing a pronunciation of *noel* unfamiliar to us.

I am certain, therefore, that *noe* is **functioning** just like *noel*. But, variant pronunciations of *noel* aside, I still have questions about its **form**.  These have led me to consider possibilities that I can’t find definitive proof for but I think are not too far-fetched (I hope!)

My first question is, why Latinise *noel* if it is a firmly established exclamation of joy?  Neither *alleluia* nor *amen* is Latinised; as interjections, they are used in their original form so why not *noel* too?

Secondly, why, if it is Latinised, end up with something that means Noah?  Why not just use its actual Latin etymological roots and say *natus est*, for example (a phrase which, of course, does appear abundantly in Latin Christmas hymns)?

### A possible answer

- During this time period, there was tension between the Church and secular society in matters of music and liturgy.  As Huot says, “the opposition … of sacred and secular poetry and music was one of the central issues in late medieval culture” (p. 17).
- The Council of Trent (1545-1563), for instance, decreed that “secular expression must be avoided” in sacred music (Fellerer, 1953, p. 576) and the Council of Trent was only another in a long line of diatribes, recommendations, reforms and bans on the secular and vernacular in sacred music.  Christmas carols were seen as “unholy liturgies” (Huot, 1997, p. 17).  As early as 1272, Daniel of Paris admonished parishioners for singing them (Huot, 1997, p. 16).  See the following for more: http://www.hymnsandcarolsofchristmas.com/History/Christmas_Music_MA.htm
- The fear was of importing “impurity and lasciviousness” (Fellerer quoting the Council) into what should be sacred and God-focussed.  The first use of *nowell* in English is in Chaucer’s *The Franklin’s Tale* (c. 1342-1400) and involves Janus wining and dining, and “every lusty man” shouting “nowell”, which seems to encapsulate all that is impure and lascivious in secular culture in the Church’s eyes!
- This could explain why *noel* itself was not used in sacred music while *alleluia* and *amen* were considered biblical in origin and hence would not need to be changed.
- *Noe* may then have been a simple solution.  It almost sounds like *noel* and can be sung in a jubilant manner, thereby recalling the joyousness of *noel* without actually using the secular word *noel*.
- Further, the happy coincidence that *noe* also means Noah could serve as a “teachable moment”.  Noah had long been established as a “type” for Christ (i.e. pre-figuring him) (Augustine, for example, had written extensively on this – Murdoch, 2003, pp. 98-99).  The bible itself says that “as in the days of Noah, so shall it be in the days of the Son of Man” – Mat. 24:37 & Luke 17:26 – an appropriate teaching at Christmas.  Further, the Hebrew meaning of Noah, depending on your etymology, means either rest or comfort (see Gen. 5:29 for the latter – “he called him Noah saying ‘he shall comfort us …’”).  Again, an entirely appropriate lesson for Christmas.
- Thus, perhaps *noe* is not so much a Latinised form of *noel* but rather a “Churchified” form of it?

References not online:

K. G. Fellerer, trans. Moses Hadas, 1953, “Church Music and the Council of Trent” in The Musical Quarterly, vol. 39, no. 4, pp. 576-594.

Sylvia Huot, 1997, Allegorical Play in the Old French Motet: The Sacred and the Profane in Thirteenth-Century Polyphony, Stanford University Press.

Brian Murdoch, 2003, The Medieval Popular Bible: Expansions of Genesis in the Middle Ages, D. S. Brewer.

Oxford English Dictionary

Latin hymns consulted:

1. *O admirabile commercium*, Johannes Regis, **c. 1425 – c. 1496**, http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/O_admirabile_commercium_(Johannes_Regis)
2. *Factor orbis*, Jacob Obrecht, **1457/8 –1505**, http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Factor_orbis_(Jacob_Obrecht)
3. *Noe*, Antoine Brumel, **c. 1460-c. 1512**, [http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Noe,*noe*(Antoine_Brumel)](http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Noe,_noe_(Antoine_Brumel))
4. *Pastores loquebantur*, earliest known arrangement is early **1500s** by Jacobus Clemens non Papa, http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Pastores_loquebantur
5. *Quaeramus cum pastoribus*, several arrangers but earliest Jean Mouton, **1459-1522**, http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Quaeramus_cum_pastoribus_(Jean_Mouton)
6. *Pastores dicite*, Cristóbal de Morales, published **1546**, http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Pastores_dicite_(Crist%C3%B3bal_de_Morales)
7. *Hodie nobis de coelo*, Jacob Regnart, published **1575**, http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Hodie_nobis_de_coelo_(Jacob_Regnart)
8. *Hodie Christus natus est*, Palestrina, published **1575**, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaQhK5sjKYI
9. *O beatum et sacrosanctum diem*, Peter Philips, published **1612**, http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/O_beatum_et_sacrosanctum_diem_(Peter_Philips)
10. *Hodie Christus natus est*, Jan Pieterszoon Sweelinck, **1562-1621**, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2d_YGFsCamI
11. *Und du Betlehem*, Johann Christenius, **1565-1626**, http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Und_du_Betlehem_(Johann_Christenius)
12. *Noe, noe*, Gregor Aichinger, **c. 1565-1628**, [http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Noe,*noe*(Gregor_Aichinger)](http://www0.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Noe,_noe_(Gregor_Aichinger))

Earliest English and French carols using *noel* I could find:

1. *Nowel! nowel! nowel! Þer is a Babe born of a may In saluacion of us*, **c1426** (OED entry for nowell)
2. *Nowel, nowel, in this halle, Make merye, I prey you alle*, **c1450** (OED entry for nowell)
3. *Sir Christmas*, composed **ca. 1461-1477**, http://www.hymnsandcarolsofchristmas.com/Hymns_and_Carols/sir_christmas.htm
4. *Therefore let us alle syng nowelle … And Cryst save mery Ynglond*, **1475** (OED entry for nowell)
5. *Nowell sing we*, **15th century**, http://www1.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Nowell_sing_we_(Anonymous)
6. *They cried with a high voice, ‘Nowell!’ clappyng their hands*, **c1500** (OED entry for nowell)
7. *The children rynnynge in the stretes cryenge nowell for ioy*e, **c1515** (OED entry for nowell)
8. *Naulet, nau, nau, nau* (French), **?15th or 16th centur**y
9. *Chantons nolet, nolet, nolet* (French), **?16th or 17th century**

Comment: Wow--I'm really impressed by your research into this. I think one of the most important points is that Latin *Noe* appeared only shortly after Old French *Noel* in the *exact same context.* The only part that strikes me as tenuous is your speculation that *Noel* was stigmatized as "lascivious" because of its use in Chaucer/Christmas carols.

Comment: Thanks!  It was a great question.  "Lascivious" isn't my word, that's a quote from the Council of Trent itself!  Although they weren't speaking specifically of Noel, they were speaking of any secular influence on the sacred.  But it's true, the second part of my answer is out on a limb somewhat.  When all is said and done, noe is clearly noel for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 4):

As a long-time Latinist and private Latin instructor for many years, When I saw «noe» first in Palestrina's *Christus natus est hodie*, I did not think of either Noah (though a nice potential callback to a great Biblical figure), nor «noël» (why in Italian?). I thought of these possible origins:

1. It's some sort of obscure interjection, rarer than, say, Heus! Eugepae! or Papae!
2. It's  some kind of Medieval mnemonic, not unlike the longer "euouae" or "evovae", which stood in for "sæculorum Amen" in numerous Medieval hymns, chants, and even snuck in at the end of a number of Medieval poems. In this way, «noe» might stand for something like "nobis omnibus" or «for all of us» (haven't figured out yet what the /e/ could stand for… I welcome suggestions).
   OR
3. It could simply be a dialectal variant of the Italian phrase "a noi" which could be an Italian translation of "nobis".
   For example:
   ⇒ Christus natus est Hodie noe = Christ is born today ***for us***

⇒ Hodie apparuit Salvator noe = Today a Savior has appeared ***for us***

After crossing cultures and the decades, «noe» might have lost that original understanding. Yet, because of its repeated use in succession in Medieval lyrics, it could have evolved into an expression of simple musical joy akin to the expression «lelolelaylo» found in many Puerto Rican Spanish songs.

Comment: These are interesting speculations...do you think they are more plausible than the above association with *Noel*? Some difficulties that come to mind: (1) I have trouble thinking that this is a nonce-interjection, especially since it only occurs in this specific context; (2) "Euouae" was used typographically to signify the corresponding syllables, but wasn't pronounced like a new word; (3) I can't think of a plausible corruption that fits in this context, e.g. "Alleluia Noe" surely doesn't mean "Alleluia to us."